# How to deal with many-to many relation between 3 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I have a problem here ,I don't know how to deal with a relation which associate 3 tables in many to many relationship

I have 3 Models (Component,Group,Permission)

Group authorize for many components and Component may be authorized by many groups

Permission may assigned to many groups and Group has many permissions

So there should be a One-to-Many relation between every (component,group) and permission
to make a group have one permission to one component

So I construct a components_groups_permissions table {component_id,group_id,permission_id}

Component Model

```
     has_many :groups, through: :components_groups_permissions
     has_many :permissions, through: :components_groups_permissions
     has_many :components_groups_permissions
```

Group Model

```
     has_many :components, through: :components_groups_permissions
     has_many :permissions, through: :components_groups_permissions
     has_many :components_groups_permissions
```

Permission Model

```
     has_many :components, through: :components_groups_permissions
     has_many :groups, through: :components_groups_permissions
     has_many :components_groups_permissions
```

ComponentsGroupsPermission Model

```
     belongs_to :component
     belongs_to :group
     belongs_to :permission
```

how can I add records or retrieve records by this relation

EDIT:
my components like directories 
permissions like allow_to_rename,allow_to_delete

Comment: from which table do you want to retrieve items?

Comment: I need to retrieve items form the relation to answer questions like  what is the permissions of groupA for componentA

Comment: @Mostafa your component is not making much sense you need to give more information on how you want to use these models

Comment: @Babar please read my edit

Comment: if you want more help, give us examples of what you want to query

Comment: For example:
How can I add record to this association 
Groups.componentsgroupspermissions<<[Permission.first,Component.first]


How can I retrieve permissions for a group and a component
Group.first.find(Component.first).permissions

Comment: you want to rename and delete all the associated models that are related to ComponentsGroupsPermission model?

Comment: do you have controllers or you simply want to create a record in the console?

Comment: I just want to add records from console if it is possible 
Do you have a solution by controllers?

Comment: well easiest way of doing it through consoles is that you do this
`entry=ComponentsGroupsPermission`, `entry.component_id= (id of a component)`,  `entry.group_id= (id of a group)`,  `entry.permission_id= (id of a permission)`, `entry.save`

Comment: @Babar Yes , I can do it also by simpler way ComponentsGroupsPermission.create!(component_id: Component.first.id,group_id: Group.first.id,permission_id: Permission.first.id)
but what about rails inner methods like "<<"

Comment: see for using rails you will have to tell us more, how exactly you want to create the relations, and are these independent models pre built when you want to create an object of this complex model  `ComponentsGroupsPermission`

Comment: In many to many relation I can create relation like this  model . collection s<<Collection , I want the same way and the same for retrieve datavi want to use rails magical way to do it :D

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to find all `componentsgroupspermissions` that belong to `a specific component. Here is how you wold query it:

```
Component.find(:id).componentsgroupspermissions
```